# Mpd некорректное значение громкости

Tags: linux, alsa

Установил mpd. При попытке выставить громкость значения не совсем или совсем не корректные.

```
mpc volume 100
volume:100%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 95
volume: 94%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 85
volume: 84%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 72
volume: 71%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 65
volume: 63%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 45
volume: 45%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 33
volume: 32%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 21
volume: 20%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 9
volume:  0%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 2
volume: 19%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 12
volume:  0%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 14
volume: 19%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 15
volume:  0%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 16
volume: 19%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 17
volume:  0%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 19
volume: 20%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 20
volume: 20%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 21
volume: 21%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 22
volume: 22%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 23
volume: 24%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 23
volume: 22%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume 9
volume:  0%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume +9
volume: 19%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
mpc volume -9
volume:  0%   repeat: on    random: off   single: off   consume: off
```

Пример конфига

```
audio_output {
        type            "alsa"
        name            "My ALSA Device"
        device          "hw:CARD=Codec,DEV=0"
        mixer_device    "default"
        mixer_control   "Line Out"
        mixer_index     "0"
}
```

Вывод amixer

```
Simple mixer control 'Line In',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch cswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 7
  Front Left: Playback 7 [100%] [6.00dB] [on] Capture [off]
  Front Right: Playback 7 [100%] [6.00dB] [on] Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'Line Out',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 17 [55%] [-21.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 17 [55%] [-21.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Line Out Source',0
  Capabilities: penum
  Items: 'Stereo' 'Mono Differential'
  Item0: 'Mono Differential'
  Item1: 'Mono Differential'
Simple mixer control 'Mic1',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch cswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 7
  Front Left: Playback 7 [100%] [6.00dB] [off] Capture [off]
  Front Right: Playback 7 [100%] [6.00dB] [off] Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic1 Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 7 [100%] [42.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mic2',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch cswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 7
  Front Left: Playback 7 [100%] [6.00dB] [off] Capture [off]
  Front Right: Playback 7 [100%] [6.00dB] [off] Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic2 Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 7 [100%] [42.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mixer',0
  Capabilities: cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Front Left: Capture [off]
  Front Right: Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mixer Reversed',0
  Capabilities: cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Front Left: Capture [off]
  Front Right: Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'ADC Gain',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cvolume-joined
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 7
  Mono: Capture 7 [100%] [6.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'DAC',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 63
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 63 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 63 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'DAC Reversed',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [off]
  Front Right: Playback [off]
```

Вывод amixer set "Line Out" 0%

```
Simple mixer control 'Line Out',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-99999.99dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-99999.99dB] [on]
```

Вывод amixer set "Line Out" 100%

```
Simple mixer control 'Line Out',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 31 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

Вывод for i in $(seq 0 31); do amixer set "Line Out" $i; done | grep 'Front Left:'

```
Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-99999.99dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 1 [3%] [-99999.99dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 2 [6%] [-43.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 3 [10%] [-42.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 4 [13%] [-40.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 5 [16%] [-39.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 6 [19%] [-37.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 7 [23%] [-36.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 8 [26%] [-34.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 9 [29%] [-33.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 10 [32%] [-31.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 11 [35%] [-30.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 12 [39%] [-28.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 13 [42%] [-27.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 14 [45%] [-25.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 15 [48%] [-24.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 16 [52%] [-22.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 17 [55%] [-21.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 18 [58%] [-19.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 19 [61%] [-18.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 20 [65%] [-16.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 21 [68%] [-15.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 22 [71%] [-13.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 23 [74%] [-12.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 24 [77%] [-10.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 25 [81%] [-9.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 26 [84%] [-7.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 27 [87%] [-6.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 28 [90%] [-4.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 29 [94%] [-3.00dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 30 [97%] [-1.50dB] [on]
  Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

Вывод amixer set "Line Out" 17% | grep 'Front Left:'

```
Front Left: Playback 6 [19%] [-37.50dB] [on]
```

Comment: подразумевая, что все значения корректные, можно вывод `amixer`, а также `amixer set "Line Out" 0%` и `amixer set "Line Out" 100%`?

Comment: И, определённости ради, что это за железка?

Comment: @Fat-Zer  Добавил в вопрос вывод команд. Железка orangepi.

Comment: А можно ещё посмотреть `for i in $(seq 0 31); do amixer set "Line Out" $i; done | grep 'Front Left:'`, а ещё `amixer set "Line Out" 17% | grep 'Front Left:`?

Comment: похоже, с одной стороны, тут баг в mpd (он криво округлаяет нужное значение звука), а с другой не совсем корректные возвращаемые значения драйвером…

Comment: @Fat-Zer добавил в вопрос)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое поведение — результат [бага](https://github.com/MusicPlayerDaemon/MPD/issues/822) в `mpd`, который был исправлен к версии `21.5`.

Обычно он вызывал лишь небольшие скачки (в 1—2%) при установке громкости, но т.к. с одной стороны регулировка громкости на плате достаточно грубая (всего 32 возможных значения), а с другой драйвер выдаёт некорректные значения для минимального поддерживаемого уровня (`-99999.99`), то в районе 0 происходят скачки сразу на `19%`.

---

#### Что делать

- Обновиться до `mpd-21.5` (уже есть в testing'е Debian'а (bookworm)). Громкость всё равно будет изменяться ступенчато, в диапазоне 0—19% регулировать уровень громкости, скорей всего, не получится, но результаты будут более адекватные: при указании конкретного значения будет конкретные уровень громкости.
- Использовать программный контроль громкости (добавить `mixer_type "software"` в конфиг вместо других параметров микшера). Возможно будет регулировать громкость более плавно, но возрастёт нагрузка на ЦП.