# Проверить статус mplayer и текущий плейлист

Tags: linux, аудио

Mplayer запускается в фоновом режиме по расписанию. Хотелось бы определять текущий статус mplayer - play, pause, stop и узнать текущий плейлист и/или проигрываемый файл.

Comment: mplayer не особо предназначен для такого, так что чкорей всего придётся делать что-то грязное вроде парсинга его вывода

Comment: @Fat-Zer, печально. Может быть тогда посоветуете какой-то другой плеер? Пробовал mpd и mocp, но с ними есть проблемы, которые не могу решить.

Comment: mpd выглядит логичным выбором, если нужно проигрывать аудио в бекграунде, а видео не нужно… с mplayer'ом я, кстати, малость поторопился: его можно запустить в [подчинённом](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt) режиме и тогда через ввод общаться с ним командами…

Comment: а ещё приятней выглядит ipc-сокет в `mpv`. Есть даже готовый [скриптик](https://github.com/lwilletts/mpvc/blob/master/mpvc), который оборачивает `socat` на манер `mpc`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer с mpd  у меня проблема в том, что устанавливаемое значение громкости ставиться не корректно. Вот тут спрашивал [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1375720/mpd-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8] . Я пробовал запускать mplayer в подчиненном режиме и одновременно в фоновом формате - как-то не взлетает + проблемы с максимальной громкостью.

Comment: Ищите по ключевому слову **MPRIS** (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MPRIS). По-моему его даже патчили на эту тему. (@FatZer большинство UI-ориентированных его умеют) https://github.com/mtijink/mpris-mplayer